# Linking error while compiling

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compilation, linker

I got iOS app, and when i try to build my project XCode give me this error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's happening? How should i solve this problem?

Error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_TrackInfo in /Users/Development/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/turbomusic-ezqahcxcowedlgaylyjxqdieywsn/Build/Intermediates/turbomusic.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/turbomusic.build/Objects-normal/i386/PlayerView.o and /Users/Development/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/turbomusic-ezqahcxcowedlgaylyjxqdieywsn/Build/Intermediates/turbomusic.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/turbomusic.build/Objects-normal/i386/turbomusicAppDelegate.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What's the rest of the error? (It should have printed a few lines before that.)

Comment: As @PhillipMills has already stated, you need to give me detail here. As this is only one piece of the error message we can't really help. It's quite likely that you haven't included a Framework in your build or you've not linked an external library properly. But without more info this is guess work at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`turbomusicAppDelegate.m` and `PlayerView.m` both declare a class named `TrackInfo`. This could be either because you have an actual duplicate of the class in both files (or the header files they include), or you are including the header which includes `TrackInfo` in both files without using include guards, in this case its probably better to use the `#import` directive rather than the `#include` one, because the compiler makes sure that the header is only included once when you use `#import`.

Comment: i dont use #include and in my turbomusicAppDelegate.m there isnt TrackInfo anywhere ((

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov Well, the linker does find a duplicate of the TrackInfo class in both files. Its hard to guess what the exact problem is and at what line it is without seeing the source code, but now that you know what caused the error, you might be able to track it down yourself. Otherwise you need to edit your question with more relevant source code so we can help you further.